# language is not changing in my partial view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented language support for my MVC 3 project.

```
     protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //It's important to check whether session object is ready
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)this.Session["Culture"];
            //Checking first if there is no value in session 
            //and set default language 
            //this can happen for first user's request
            if (ci == null)
            {
                //Sets default culture to english invariant
                string langName = "en";
                //Try to get values from Accept lang HTTP header
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages != null &&
   HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages.Length != 0)
                {
                    //Gets accepted list 
                    langName = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0].Substring(0, 2);
                }
                ci = new CultureInfo(langName);
                this.Session["Culture"] = ci;
            }
            //Finally setting culture for each request
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
        }
    }
```

And then i choose my language by this :

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ChangeLanguage(string lang, string returnUrl)
    {
        Session["Culture"] = new CultureInfo(lang);

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

It loads the correct language in the main views but not in the partial views. Am i missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with this code. Could you explain what do you mean when you say that the correct language doesn't load in partials? How are you rendering those partials? Could you show the view and the partial?

Comment: well it's enough unlikely but maybe you are trying to change culture during ajax request? When Application_AcquireRequestState is hiring?

Comment: Darin: I found the problem.....on the actionresult there was an attribute named OutputCashe for 30 min, which meant that when i changed the language it didnt call the partial view again...sorry for all this, i should have noticed that. But is this way "ok" to do a language support?

Comment: I wouldn't use the session to store the current language. I would use a route parameter. Makes your site more SEO friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darin was right, code was correct.